# excel vba: Can someone help me understand how to use a cusom sort order?

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I've been working on a code to sort a block of data using `Range.Sort` using a custom sort order. I've tried to record macros and look online but came up more confused about this problem.

1. For the `key1:=` argument; is it a single cell (e.g. `Range("A1")`) or a whole column?
2. How exactly can I use a custom sort order in `OrderCustom:=`?
3. In the case I'm going about this all wrong; the `Range` in `Range.Sort` can be anywhere as long as its in one continuous block, correct?

Here is the code I'm working with:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim quantity As Variant
        quantity = 2 + WorkshetFunction.Count(Range("A" & 3, "K" & 900))

    With Range("A" & 3, "K" & quantity)
        .Sort key1:=Range("A" & 3) 
              Order:=xlAscending
              Header:=xlNo
              OrderCustom:="VALID, GOOD, DUE, OVERDUE, WAY OVERDUE, MISSING" 
                '> This is the order in which I want the items on this list sorted by.
    End With
End Sub
```

The `Range("A" & 3, "K" & quantity)` refers to a block of data containing on `"A"` the "status" of some items determined by their calibration expiration dates, amongst other data which is irrelevant for this  purpose, and  I'm not in the liberty to share. All I'm asking is help understanding the inner workings of the `.Sort` method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give'r

```
Sub SortItOut()
    Dim rng As Range, sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
    With sh
        Set rng = .Range("A3:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "K").End(xlUp).Row)
        With rng
            sh.Sort.SortFields.Clear
            sh.Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A3") _
                                 , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, CustomOrder:= _
                                   "VALID,GOOD,DUE,OVERDUE,WAY OVERDUE,MISSING", DataOption:=xlSortNormal
        End With
        With .Sort
            .SetRange rng
            .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
            .Apply
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Magic or witchcraft? Works like a charm, thank you. How does this differ from `Range.Sort`?